# I am trying to transfer the value from one task to another from callback with gulp 4, but have error

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, gulp

Im trying to create git deploy, with gulp 4. But gulp 4 gives an error, and recommends using gulp series. How i can using gulp.series, if i need to get the value from the function response?

In example, im using plugin gulp-confirm. In order for the user to enter the commit text. U can see this in .pipe(confirm({ ... that function return "answer" in property "proceed". That answer must be in ".pipe(git.commit(answer))", how i can do that guys? Im not best in es6...

// deploy system

```
gulp.task('set-prod-env', function (done) {
  process.env.NODE_ENV = 'production';
  done();
});


function gitCommit() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    gulp.src('config.rb')
      .pipe(confirm({
        // Static text.
        question: 'Pls write commit text',
        proceed: function(answer) {
          return gulp.src(' ')
            .pipe(git.add({args: '--all'}))
            .pipe(git.commit(answer));
        }
      }))
      .pipe(gulp.dest('./'));
      resolve();
  })
}

function gitPush(done) {
  git.push('origin', 'dev', function (err) {
    if (err) throw err;
  });
  done();
}

gulp.task('deploy', gulp.series('set-prod-env', 'build', gitCommit, gitPush));
```

Now code is work, but with error, maybe someone can show better example, with Gulp 4, gulp 4 is different form gulp 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple problems with the code:

1. You stream a single file into `confirm` and want to prompt for a text
2. There are multiple issues with handling asynchronous returns / callbacks
3. What you want to do is not really what you put into code

So from my understanding, you want to have a commit task, that builds your project, then adds all files and then commits it, based on user input.

A quick and dirty solution to this might be using [readline-sync](https://www.npmjs.com/package/readline-sync) as you want to wait until commit is finished anyways.

The following code should be more to the direction you want to go. It's untested though, as I didn't want to create a new repository to test this... :)

I've added a few comments to show the intention and where I changed something where I saw issues with the original code. Hope this helps!

```
// import `readlineSync` to simplify the command line prompt
// I've never used it myself, there might be better ways to do this!
const readlineSync = require('readline-sync');

gulp.task('set-prod-env', function (done) {
  process.env.NODE_ENV = 'production';
  done();
  // Actually, you wouldn't need to have `done` as parameter and call it, as this function is synchronous. As soon as the function is at the end, it's done (if it did not return a promise, stream or wants to call the `done` callback.
});

// Using a single file to create a stream to use some prompt about a stream
// is a very hacky way to do this and I wouldn't try to do that. To make
// this simpler, I've changed it to synchronously wait for an answer here
// before starting / returning the pipeline
function gitCommit() {
  // this should block gulp completely until you answered the question
  const commitMessage = readlineSync.question('Please write your commit message');
  // this returns the actual action of `gitCommit`
  return gulp.src('.')
    .pipe(git.add({args: '--all'}))
    .pipe(git.commit(commitMessage));
}

// this function returned before `git.push` is really done.
// It might not cause issues as "push" is the last action in your pipeline,
// but you might run into issues if you want to do something AFTER `gitPush`.
function gitPush(done) {
  git.push('origin', 'dev', function (err) {
    if (err) return done(err); // this will send the error to the caller (gulp), if there was one
    done(); // this should be called when `git.push` is done - i.e. inside of its callback
  });
  // you could simplify this to:
  // git.push('origin', 'dev', done);
}

gulp.task('deploy', gulp.series('set-prod-env', 'build', gitCommit, gitPush));
```